# Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout and explicitly having to call done()

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, jestjs, redux-thunk

I'm currently writing tests for a React Native app and I'm curious about the best implementation to support async methods from Redux Thunk. `tryLogin` is a function that returns an async function calling dispatch (classic Redux thunk). At the beginning of the login process, LOG_USER is dispatched and at the end if success, LOG_USER_SUCCESS.

The problem is that the tests don't end if I don't call `done` explictly, even if I don't have very long calls/tasks in my function (API and AsyncStorage calls are mocked). My async function shows success and then the tests hangs until the 5000ms timeout and fail.

I believe that I could replace this implementation with async/await, which would be more logic to me but my attempt wasn't very conclusive...

```
/* @flow */
import { tryLogin } from '@actions/user'
import { LOG_USER, LOG_USER_ERROR, LOG_USER_SUCCESS } from '@constants/user'
import axios from 'axios'
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter'
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import findTargetEnvironnmement from '@modules/findTargetEnvironnement'

const middlewares = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares)
const axiosMockAdapter = new MockAdapter(axios)
const store = mockStore({})

// Override user connection
jest.mock('@react-native-community/async-storage')

describe('Test user async actions', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    store.clearActions()
  })

  // Success Workflow test
  it('should call LOG_USER_SUCCESS', done => {
    const targetUrl = findTargetEnvironnmement()
    if (!targetUrl) {
      return done.fail(
        new ReferenceError('Target environnement is not defined')
      )
    }

    axiosMockAdapter.onPost(`${targetUrl}/session`).reply(200, {
      active: true,
      session_token: 'token',
    })
    axiosMockAdapter.onGet(`${targetUrl}/user`).reply(200, {
      email: 'test@test.fr',
      first_name: 'Test',
    })

    const expectedActions = [
      { type: LOG_USER },
      {
        type: LOG_USER_SUCCESS,
        data: { active: true, session_token: 'token' },
        infos: { email: 'test@test.fr', first_name: 'Test' },
      },
    ]
    store.dispatch(tryLogin('test@test.fr', 'testtest')).then(() => {
      // return of async actions
      expect.assertions(1)
      expect(store.getActions()).toMatchObject(expectedActions)
      done()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: hhmmm. let's try with moving `expect.assertions(1)` to the function's top and replacing `done.fail` with `throw`(there is nothing like `done.fail`, it's ordinary callback). probably you just missing error message about code failed.

Comment: Removing `done.fail()` solved my problem! Do I even need to await my action `tryLogin`?  (it's a function that returns an async function)

Comment: async function returns Promise. you can either `await` on it or use it with `.then()` chained. It's up to you.